# php multidimensional array iterative recursively

Tags: php

I want to insert extra key before of array if key exists and array is not multi dimensional for example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [_key_] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [pub-id-type] => pmid
                            [value] => 25588809
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [pub-id-type] => pmc
                            [value] => 4302133
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [pub-id-type] => publisher-id
                            [value] => 1008
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [pub-id-type] => doi
                            [value] => 10.1186/s12885-015-1008-4
                        )

                    [type_s] => article-id
                    [id] => 58a6eeedeab2f
                )

        )
```

I want:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [_key_] => Array
                (
[0]=>array(
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [pub-id-type] => pmid
                            [value] => 25588809
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [pub-id-type] => pmc
                            [value] => 4302133
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [pub-id-type] => publisher-id
                            [value] => 1008
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [pub-id-type] => doi
                            [value] => 10.1186/s12885-015-1008-4
                        )

                    [type_s] => article-id
                    [id] => 58a6eeedeab2f
                )
        )
)
```

recursively util n depath of `_Key_` is found.

Comment: what is you desired array for this above one ?

Answer (score 0):

The layout is not the best, but howerver ...

try this one:

```
if(is_array($arr[0][_key_]))
{
    $tmp = $arr[0][_key_];
    unset($arr[0][_key_]);
    $arr[0][_key_][] = $tmp;
}
```